# UIButton function is not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

Hi and thanks in advance for you support :)

So what I am doing is:
1. create a scroll view and add it to the main view
2. then to the scroll view add another UIView that is as large as the scroll view;
3. and in the UIView add a programmatically created button to witch I also add: tag, image, size programmatically.

Order of adding(parenting) objects:
UIView->UIScrollView->UIView->UIButton

And here is the code I am using:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
    UIButton *button;
    UIView *buttonHolderView;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize scroll;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    //scroll view is added using storyboards
    [scroll setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [scroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(1840, 1752)];
    scroll.bounces = NO;
    [scroll setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    //UPDATE 4
    //here changed to integer coordinates and now it works
    buttonHolderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake( scroll.frame.origin.x, scroll.frame.origin.y, scroll.frame.size.width, scroll.frame.size.height)];
    [buttonHolderView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    [scroll addSubview:buttonHolderView];

    NSString *title = @"";
    int tagForTheButton = 0;

    button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
    button.frame = CGRectMake(xPossition, yPossition, 200, 64);
    button.tag = tagForTheButton;
    [button setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed: ) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [buttonHolderView addSubview:button];
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Tile.png"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    //other scroll and pinch gesture adjustments
    //UPDATE WITH CODE FOR PINCH AND SCROLL 


   [scroll setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pitchGestureRecognizer = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePitch:)];
    [scroll addGestureRecognizer:pitchGestureRecognizer];

    imageMaxScale = 1.1;
    imageMinScale = 0.2;
    imageCurrentScale = 1.0;



    yMyCharacterFrame = 200;
    xMyCharacterFrame = 200;
    myCharacterFrame = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
    myCharacterFrame.frame = CGRectMake(xMyCharacterFrame, yMyCharacterFrame, 100, 100);
    myCharacterFrame.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image0.png"];
    [myCharacterFrame setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [scroll addSubview:myCharacterFrame];
}

-(void)handlePitch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *) pinchGesture{

    if (imageCurrentScale * [pinchGesture scale] > imageMinScale && imageCurrentScale * [pinchGesture scale] <imageMaxScale) {
        imageCurrentScale = imageCurrentScale * [pinchGesture scale];
        CGAffineTransform zoomTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(imageCurrentScale, imageCurrentScale);
        [[pinchGesture view] setTransform:zoomTransform];
    }


    [pinchGesture setScale:1.0];
    CGRect scrollFrame;
    scrollFrame.origin = _mainViewHolder.frame.origin;
    scrollFrame.size = CGSizeMake(568, 320);
    scroll.frame = scrollFrame;

}

-(void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender{
    NSLog(@"button pressed");   
}
```

The button is drawn on screen but when I try to tap it, it doesn't enter the buttonPressed function(doesn't NSLog).

Any suggestions?
Also I didn't understood what addTarget refers to(I have read the apple documentation).

UPDATE 2:
If I add the button to the scroll view than not only that it is displayed but I can also tap it.

UPDATE 3: 
I HAVE RUNNED: po [scroll recursiveDescription].
It returned:

```
UIScrollView: 0x7f95c9c7adf0; frame = (0 0; 320 568); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7f95c9c7f5f0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f95c9c79820>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {1840, 1752}>
   | <UIImageView: 0x7f95c9c7ed40; frame = (317.5 561; 2.5 7); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = LM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f95c9c7ec20>>
   | <UIImageView: 0x7f95c9c7d2f0; frame = (313 565.5; 7 2.5); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f95c9c7dda0>>
   | <UIButton: 0x7f95c9d9f9c0; frame = (0 0; 320 568); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f95c9d9e750>>
   |    | <UIButton: 0x7f95c9d9fea0; frame = (0 0; 200 64); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f95c9d96540>>
|    |    | <UIImageView: 0x7f95c9cc4590; frame = (0 0; 200 64); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f95c9cc4690>>
```

AND:

```
(lldb) po [button recursiveDescription]
<UIButton: 0x7f95cd24e1f0; frame = (0 0; 200 64); opaque = NO; tag = 0; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f95cd24e100>>
   | <UIImageView: 0x7f95cd251b70; frame = (0 0; 200 64); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f95cd251c70>>
```

UPDATE 4:
The code seems to work just fine after changed to integer:
 buttonHolderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake( scroll.frame.origin.x, scroll.frame.origin.y, scroll.frame.size.width, scroll.frame.size.height)];

Thanks for all your help especially to [DoertyDoerk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1514938/doertydoerk) who showed something completely new to me.

Comment: The `user Interaction Enabled` option is off for the scroll? I tried your code and it worked.

Comment: Suggestion 1: look for any superview of the button with `userInteractionEnabled` set to `NO`.

Comment: Suggestion 2: as a test, remove all gesture recognizers. They can interfere with touch events.

Comment: set buttonHolderView.userInteractionEnabled = true;

Comment: Yes in my code it is turned on: [scroll setUserInteractionEnabled:YES]; and is not working..

Comment: but is the target correct?

Comment: also I have enabled the interaction for the buttonHolderView and still nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code for the button itself looks fine. Except for the xPossition, yPossition bit it compiled nicely and the `buttonPressed:` is being called. I would suspect a problem with your view hierarchy as already suggested in earlier comments. I'd set a breakpoint at the end of your `viewDidLoad: method. Then on the break in the console type the following command and check if your button gets overlaid.

`po [[UIWindow keyWindow] recursiveDescription]`

You may want to copy&paste the result into your text editor for easier reading.

Hope that helps!
[image]

Comment: I've added a screenshot to my earlier answer. When the app hits the breakpoint just copy&past the command I pointed out to you into the console window on the lower right of the Xcode screen as shown above and press return. You also may want to try to break at the end of `-viewDidAppear` if the results are not conclusive.

Comment: when I write the command it returns nil on the next row, what should it do?

Comment: I just google it and it seems an alternative to "Debug View Hierarchy", I will try both of them, I sow something about this a few months ago but I didn't know what it was and how to use it, thx for the starting point

Comment: I have runed: (lldb) po [scroll recursiveDescription]

Comment: Check your second trace, line 2 where it provides details about the background image. Here it says **userInteractionEnabled = NO**. I'd set this to YES in `-viewDidLoad`or get rid of it altogether at least for testing.

Comment: removed the background image of the button but it is still not tappable

Comment: Did you also set button.userInteractionEnabled = YES; ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68669/discussion-between-doertydoerk-and-bianca-ioana).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try this:

```
[buttonHolderView bringSubviewToFront:button];
```

Comment: Seems almost like "You can see me, but you can't touch me"
The button is visible, but maybe it's in a smaller frame. Example: frame with height 100 and the button with 120 y position you can see it but not tap it.